# How to find p-value from biserial.cor function?

Tags: correlation

I want to calculate correlation between two parameters. 
`y` is  nominal scale (0 and 1)

```
library(ltm)
x <- c(1,2,5,0,6,3,4)
y <- c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0)
```

I found `ltm` package which provide `biserial.cor` function.

```
test <-  biserial.cor (x,y)
```

How can I find out `p-value` from this function?

Thank you so much for all suggestion and answers.

Comment: the output is itself p value.